# SSD life with encryption and VHDX containers

Tags: ssd, virtual-machine, encryption, virtualization, hyper-v

**My Question:**

1. How does both encryption and Virtualization affect SSD life?
2. Does the whole file gets written every time I write to the
   partition? Or Does it only happen when I unmount?
3. Should I create it as dynamic?
4. or Should I just create it as regular partition?

The reason I want to create a dynamic VHDX container is because that way I'll have more effective storage since I won't use the whole 64 GB right away (and will upgrade SSD down the line).

**Setup:**
Windows 10 64bit pro + Bitlocker + Hyper-V and disk Management VHDX.

I'm buying a new laptop for gaming and work, 512 gb SSD, I'm looking to have three partitions:
128 GB for Windows Partitions
64 GB Encrypted partition for work data. (Bitlocker)
the rest would be regular data partition like game library and unimportant data.

I'm looking to separate work and personal so I thought about creating an Hyper-V VHDX 64 GB Partition for work that will be encrypted
So the setup would be
128 GB System
Rest for regular partition, Which include an 64 GB VHDX that is encrypted and used as both mount for Host OS + Mount for virtual machine.

I've looked up answers about this but couldn't find an updated match (also found contradicting info).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writes happen (largely) in the same pattern as if the virtual machine were a genuine host with some caveats.

- **Dynamic Disk** For a dynamic disk there will be extra writes every time the dynamic disk is expanded as the host filesystem is updated to allocate those extra blocks into the file and the file itself updated to state which blocks are used. In theory these extra writes should only happen the first time a block allocated, rewriting already allocated blocks will not incur an extra write.
  For many VMs this will be a one-off cost as the disk expands, once the VM hits its disk limit it will not expand further and writes will be the same as a host.
  For the guest disk to expand by 1MB I would expect only a handful of extra kilobytes to be written on the host, it will certainly not be a double the 1MB or more.
- **Snapshots** If you have snapshots enabled then all writes get captured to another file and your original VM disk-file will be effectively read only. You will end up with another file experiencing growth instead of your main VM file. Merging the snapshot back in will overwrite the original and cause more writes in that file.
- **Static Disk** For a static disk the "disk" is already allocated and no extra writes will happen.

Your specific questions:

> 1. How does both encryption and Virtualization affect SSD life?

Encryption will make no difference, as far as the disk is concerned it is all just data.
Virtualisation may have some extra writes due to dynamic disk growth as above, but once growth stops then there will be no more writes than would be experienced by a "normal" computer.

> 2. Does the whole file gets written every time I write to the partition? Or Does it only happen when I unmount?

If the guest writes to it's disk then that write gets put out to the disk backing it on the host.

If you have snapshotting enabled then you may have a different file experiencing writes, and "flattening" the snapshot will copy that data back to the main file causing more writes to happen that way.

> 3. Should I create it as dynamic?

See above. If you can accept a moderate extra overhead then do it. It's not going to double the amount of writes, but will cause a small amount of extra overhead.

> 4. or Should I just create it as regular partition?

This may give a small performance gain over a file method, but is essentially no different to a static-sized VM in terms of number of writes to disk. What you will loose is the ability to simply move the VM file to another disk or copy it using normal methods like Explorer.

Largely though a VM will not result in significantly more writes than using a machine normally. You've got the extra writes of installing a new machine, and then whatever else would normally have happened. There is a small amount in overhead when the disk is being expanded, but that is a one-off cost.

The extra writes will only really happen if you are *constantly* reinstalling the guest machine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was worried that the whole file gets re-written. 

Given you answer, I'm just gonna create a dynamic VHDX through disk Management and mount it as container and encrypt it, since that will allow me to virtualize it in the future when I decide to go full VM for work (since I might have to use VPN and give the IT access to the machine).

But basically mounting should be the same as virtualization so I shouldn't worry about VHDX anyways.